# Can I borrow an E-book via my Amazon Prime membership without a Kindle reader device?

Tags: amazon, kindle

So I have an Amazon Prime membership which includes one borrowing one E-Book from the Kindle shop per month. I don't have a Kindle reader, however since there are several other options to read kindle books (Cloud reader, Kindle desktop & Android app), I don't see why I shouldn't be able to use it. However, I can't seem to find any way to make use of that Prime feature. The store pages for Kindle books only offer me to buy them or sign up for a Kindle unlimited offer. I have tried the Amazon android app and the kindle app as well, to no avail. So here are my questions:

1. Can I borrow one book a month, as included in my Amazon Prime membership, without owning a Kindle reader device?
2. If so, how? I can access the Amazon web store, have the desktop kindle app installed on my PC and the Amazon app and Amazon kindle app on my android phone.
3. If so, can I borrow *any* e-book that is available via Amazon or only select from some fraction of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some research as a fellow Prime member, and it appears that you are referring to the [Kindle First](http://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/kindle/first/) program, as the only other Prime-related eBook service is the Kindle Lending Library, which is only available to actual Kindle owners.

1. Kindle First allows you to *purchase (indefinitely add to your Kindle library) for free* one eBook per month.
2. To view the available eBooks and add one to your Kindle library, visit the [Kindle First homepage](http://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/kindle/first/). You can access it at any time via any Kindle app on any device.
3. And, of course, the catch: Kindle First is a service that lets Prime members add a **single eBook from a list of six possibilities; however, all six books will not be released to the general public until the following month.** This means that you get to enjoy a book up to a month before much of the world.

Comment: I was actually talking about the Lending Library. I thought it was counterintuitive and not really fair that this service should be only available to kindle owners, even though it's advertised as one of the core features of the Prime membership. Well, at least I know now that it's not possible without a kindle device. Kindle first isn't available where I live anyway :/ Thanks!